# How to submit more than one x.editable to the same URL

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have four X.Editable link I want to submit them to the same URL how to assign each x.editable to the value to get them  each one with his right value

here is the editable link

```
 <a href="javascript:;" id="CreditOfficer" name="CreditOfficer" data-name="CreditOfficer" data-type="text" data-pk="1"
     data-original-title="Enter Name"> superuser </a>
<a href="javascript:;" id="ProgramManager" name="ProgramManager" data-name="ProgramManager" data-type="text" data-pk="2"
     data-original-title="Enter Name"> superuser </a>
  <a href="javascript:;" id="FinancialDirector" name="FinancialDirector" data-name="FinancialDirector" data-type="text" data-pk="3"
     data-original-title="Enter Name"> superuser </a>
        <a href="javascript:;" id="FoundationDirector" name="FoundationDirector" data-name="FoundationDirector" data-type="text" data-pk="4"
     data-original-title="Enter Name"> superuser </a>
```

and here is the JQuery code :

```
  var initEditables = function() {

        //set editable mode based on URL parameter
        if (App.getURLParameter('mode') == 'inline') {
            $.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'inline';
            $('#inline').attr("checked", true);
        } else {
            $('#inline').attr("checked", false);
        }

        //global settings 
        $.fn.editable.defaults.inputclass = 'form-control';
        $.fn.editable.defaults.url = 'foundationofficialsajax.php';

        $('#CreditOfficer').editable({
              validate: function(value) {
                if ($.trim(value) == '') return 'هذا الحقل مطلوب';
            },
            type: 'text',
            pk: 1,
            name: 'CreditOfficer',
            title: 'heeelp'
        });
                $('#ProgramManager').editable({
              validate: function(value) {
                if ($.trim(value) == '') return 'هذا الحقل مطلوب';
            },
            type: 'text',
            pk: 1,
            name: 'ProgramManager',
            title: 'heeelp'
        });
                $('#FinancialDirector').editable({
              validate: function(value) {
                if ($.trim(value) == '') return 'هذا الحقل مطلوب';
            },
            type: 'text',
            pk: 1,
            name: 'FinancialDirector',
            title: 'heeelp'
        });
                $('#FoundationDirector').editable({
              validate: function(value) {
                if ($.trim(value) == '') return 'هذا الحقل مطلوب';
            },
            type: 'text',
            pk: 1,
            name: 'FoundationDirector',
            title: 'heeelp'
        });

    }
```

and here is the php URL where i want to submit the values :

```
 <?php
    $constantsobj = new constants();
    $helpersobj = new helpers();
    $manger_sth = $constantsobj->getfoundationofficials();
    $manger_row = $manger_sth->fetch();
    $CreditOfficer_value =$manger_row["CreditOffice"];
    $ProgramManager_value =$manger_row["ProgramManager"];
    $FinancialDirector_value =$manger_row["FinancialDirector"];
    $FoundationDirector_value =$manger_row["FoundationDirector"];


    $pk = $_GET['pk'];

    $CreditOfficer_name =  isset($_POST["CreditOfficer"]) ?$helpersobj->prepar_data($_POST['CreditOfficer']):"";
    $CreditOfficer_value = $_POST['CreditOfficer'];


    $ProgramManager_name = isset($_POST["ProgramManager"]) ?$helpersobj->prepar_data($_POST['ProgramManager']):"";
    $ProgramManager_value = $_POST['ProgramManager'];
    $FinancialDirector_name = isset($_POST["FinancialDirector"]) ?$helpersobj->prepar_data($_POST['FinancialDirector']):"";
    $FinancialDirector_value = $_POST['FinancialDirector'];

    $FoundationDirector_name= isset($_POST["FoundationDirector"]) ?$helpersobj->prepar_data($_POST['FoundationDirector']):"";
    $FoundationDirector_value = $_POST['FoundationDirector'];



    $status =$constantsobj->updatefoundationofficials($CreditOfficer_value , $ProgramManager_value ,$FinancialDirector_value ,$FoundationDirector_value);
    ?>
```

I want to submit each different value to the same URL , How can I do that .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the answer in case someone need it 
using the selector to access each link as separated one

```
function bind_editable_to_column(table_selector,column_selector,ajax_url,title,options) {
      options = typeof options !== 'undefined' ? options : ''; 
$(table_selector).editable({   
    selector: column_selector,
    url: ajax_url,
    title: title,
    ajaxOptions: {
          type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'json'
    },
    source: options
  });
}
```

and the ajax will be like this :

```
<?php

$employee_id = trim($_POST['pk']);
$column_name = trim($_POST['name']);
$value = trim($_POST['value']);

$result['response']['success'] = true;
$result['response']['message'] = "Updated the $column_name with $value";
echo json_encode($result);

if(strlen($employee_id) > 0 && strlen($column_name) > 0 && strlen($value) > 0) {

    //connecting to database
    try {
        $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=YOUR_DB_NAME","YOUR_USER_NAME","YOUR_PASSWORD");
    }
    catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }

    $query = "UPDATE `tbl_employees` SET {$column_name} = :value WHERE `id`=:id";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bindParam(':value',$value);
    $stmt->bindParam(':id',$employee_id);
    if($stmt->execute()) {

        //header('HTTP 200 OK', true, 200);
        $result['response']['success'] = true;
        $result['response']['message'] = "Updated the $column_name with $value";
        echo json_encode($result);
    }
    else {
        header('HTTP 400 Bad Request', true, 400);      
        echo "Error: Unable to update";     

    }

}
else {
    header('HTTP 400 Bad Request', true, 400);
    echo "One or more required values are missing.";
}

?>
```

depends on this article : 
[x.Editable to whole database table](http://codezag.com/creating-editable-html-table-x-editable/)